# Looking for help to understand group isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

I recently posted a question asking about subgroups of symmetric group, and it seemed that all responses went way beyond me and when I attempted to understand, it just seemed like there was a conversation going on that I could not understand. So I decided maybe this is partially on my part, as I should provide more information of what I understand etc. I will also cut it down.

In a few words; I am wondering about the relation between isomorphism and subgroups, how do they relate? How can I use it to help with the following, etc

$H=\{1,(423),(432),(42),(43),(23)\}$

Specifically, I want to prove or disprove that
H Is a subgroup of $S_4$

I know that to test this, it must be that it contains the identity , which it does.

It also must be that if we multiply any two elements, their product is also in H and finally that each element has an inverse in H.

It seems like a lot to test each thing;

Here is what else was suggested at, but not elaborated so I do not know if it is what was meant.

What if I say define a map as follows;

$f: H \to H'$

$(1) \to (1) , (423) \to (123) , (432) \to (132) , (42) \to (12) , (43) \to (13) , (23) \to (23)$

Then it is bijective map. And from a theorem in my notes, it follows that the groups of permutations ,  are isomorphic . But I do not know what this can tell me.

Other things I know about :

Lagranges thereom, that the order of the subgroup must divide the order of the group.

Cayleys thereom, that if G is a finite group of order n then G is isomorphic to $S_{n}$

Comment: But that is one of the things I do not understand. Why is this releveant to showing if it is a subgroup?? Cant S4 not have a subgroup of order 6 because 6 divides 24?

Comment: In general, if you are given  a subset of a group, then you have to check the closure properties, which is a bit tedious, I don't think group isomorphisms will help with this. In this example, there is an alternative. You could prove first that the set of all permutations in $S_4$ (or indeed in $S_n$ for any $n$) that map the point $1$ to itself (this is called the *stabilizer* of $1$) is a subgroup of $S_4$. Now observe that there are exactly $3! = 6$ elements in this subgroup. Your subset $H$ contains $6$ elements that all map $1$ to itself. So $H$ must be equal to that subgroup.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: You're right. One of my many typos. As it's too late toedit, I'll delete this comment, and repost it.

Comment: A finite group of order $n$ cannot be  isomorphic to $S_n$ for at least one reason: they do not have the same order ($S_n$ has order $n!$).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're going down a reasonable path, but haven't done it in quite the right way. In particular, the principal observation is that the subgroup
$$H=\{1,(423),(432),(42),(43),(23)\}$$
is exactly the permutations on the set $\{2,3,4\}$. This is, of course, closed under composition since the composition of two permutations on a set is a permutation on the same set - and we have inverses as well by definition of permutation, as well as an identity element. You can equivalently think of this as the set of permutations which have $1$ as a fixed point.

Defining a bijection from $H$ to $S_3$ is a good idea, but the key point is that this is an *isomorphism* - that is, it is a bijection satisfying $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. You don't really save yourself from having to check that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all pairs $a$ and $b$ by defining it pointwise rather than according to a pattern. However, when you see that $f$ just replaces all '4's with '1's, it's clear that it preserves the group operation (i.e. is a homomorphism) and with bijectivity it's clera that it's an isomorphism - at which point, you can see that $H$ is a group since it is isomorphic to a group.

Answer (score 0):

There is not so much to check to determine that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_4$.For example the inverses of 2-cycles are themselves and for the 3-cycles it's easy to see that they are each other inverses, and for the calculation of the product there is a similar reasoning.

But there are other solutions:

-If you want to work with isomorphisms you *a priori* don't know that $H$ is a group and so we cannot apply the usual rules of isomorphism. You know only that there is a bijection between $H$ and $H'$ which is actually $S_3$. But we can notice that the number $4$ in $H$ has the same, identic function of the element $1$ in $H'=S_3$, like they are mute variables, only the symbol has changed, so the multiplication in $H$ works the same as the multiplication in $S_3$ and so for the structure of $H$ it is a subgroup of $S_4$ in particular $H$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

-Another way, that is quite the same of the above solution, is to see at the problem from another point of view. We can look at $H$ as the set of permutation of ${2,3,4}$, that has $3!=6$ elements, and is a group because every *permutation group* is a **group**.

Answer (score 0):

The map you mention defines $H$ as in bijection with $S_3$, and this map is compatible with the composition of parmutations. Indeed, $H$ consists of all permutations of $\{2,3,4\}$. It is a group on its own right for the composition of permutations, and the canonical injection of $H$ in $S_n$ for any $n\ge 4$ is a group homomorphism. Hence $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ for any $n\ge 4$, and even *is* a subgroups if $n=4$.

Comment: And so with this, can I use that the image of f is a subgroup of S3? And is that also saying it is a subgroup of S4 , and even Sn for n greater than that

Comment: Isn't it clear the groups  of permutations of any $3$ objects are isomorphic, whatever these sets of $3$ objects are? Indeed you can consider $H$ a subgroup of any $S_n$ with $n\ge 4$, and as *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $S_3$.